# Is there a maximum number that a numpy array can hold? I can't explain weird behaviour with a numpy array

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have a very simple question but as hard as I've tried, I haven't been able to find an answer to it.

I have a time grid, defined with a range between 1 and 601.
I elevated that grid to the third power and multiplied it by 45.
It should have just given a cubic curve. It didn't, instead, weird oscillations take place and I just can't figure out why that is the case.

Below are the code and the plot that I get:

```py
t_grid = np.array(range(1,601))
term3 = 45 * t_grid**3
plt.plot(term3)
```

[image]

Comment: Just `t_grid = np.arange(1, 601, dtype=float)`. Or in this case even `np.arange(1, 601, dtype=int64)`.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer.

It is an overflow error.

More info https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10964

```
t_grid = np.array(range(1,100001))
t_grid = t_grid.astype('float64') 
term3 = t_grid*t_grid
```